# Global variables use to much space in the dynamic memory

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, library, memory-usage

I use two simple libraries (see [1](https://github.com/t0mpr1c3/Arduino-PID-AutoTune-Library/tree/6329d97eb00431efdf1dd0cc540c3a63347ed1f7/PID_AutoTune_v0), [2](https://github.com/br3ttb/Arduino-PID-Library/)) I found online for my code on the Arduino Uno, unfortunately I also use ROS and all those libraries take away to much space, when I compile my code I get this error:

```
Global variables use 2,112 bytes (103%) of dynamic memory, leaving -64 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
```

I shortened my Strings, but it was not enough. How can I change the code in the libraries to achieve less used memory?

I think I don't understand the concept of global variables completely. For example I changed all `double` variables in the libraries to `float` variables, but it did not change dynamic memory use at all. How can I use less memory?

Comment: Did you placed your string literals into the flash memory?

Comment: I shortened them down to 1 letter, to see how far it reduces the size, but putting it into flash memory won't solve the problem, since it is not enough.

Comment: Well, then you should provide your code so we can try it...

Comment: I checked and about 75% of global variables are already used by the libraries I use. Since they are open source I was hopping to change those. They are provided in the links I gave in my question.

Comment: A very generic description: Variables that hang around (global, static, ect) are assigned their own memory location in RAM, variables that have limited scope are temporarily assigned a memory location in the RAM in an area called the stack & variables that never change can be put into program memory.  On an embedded processor this usually means putting variable into flash.

Comment: This is "off the cuff" advice, hence it is only a comment, not an answer, but, if you are hurting for memory why not switch to an ARM based Arduino.  Many ARM based Arduino's have much more memory than, say, an Uno.

Comment: How many of those objects do you instanciate? The most obvious candidate for memory saving is `double lastInputs[100];` in `class PID_ATune`. It takes 400 bytes. If you shorten this array, make sure you don't access it out of bonds.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I reduced the number to 80, it helped, thank you! Why does it not change memory consumption if I change the double to float?

Comment: @Jonas, because on arduino, double and float have the same size : https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Float or https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Double

Comment: The first library defines a class `PID_ATune` which contains a lot of members, including an array of 100 `double`, i.e. 400 bytes for each instance of `PID_ATune`. Not sure so many double are needed there, but you could first try to reduce this number.

Comment: have you solved this, I am facing the same exact issue! as I am currently using the autotune library ! and can't optimize the sample code! please help

Comment: Unfortunately I could not solve the issue. I think I moved to a larger microcontroller that time. Sorry. You could try to use the source code of the autotune library directly and fine tune it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write a program, some memory can be determined in compilation time, due to it's predefinition, (`float` and `double` in Arduino - not Due model - use 4 bytes each - in Due, `double` uses 8 bytes for 64 bit precision).

But there is some memory that only can be known at runtime; where we are talking about objects (or arrays determined by user input). In these cases, programs need to dynamically allocate memory, for which the C++ language integrates the operators `new` and `delete`. More info at: [Dynamic memory](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/).

You should control the creation of objects and arrays (those are created with `new` and then deleted with `delete`).

If your requirements are greater than the resources of any Arduino (except Arduino Due), you should change to the Due model, which has more memory space and computing power (but changes the 5 V to 3.3 V, be careful).

Comment: There is also the Mega 2560, which has the same architecture as the Uno (AVR), but 4 times as much RAM.

Answer (score 2):

@jonas I had a similar problem not quite exceeding the limit.  One item you can do is move the strings to Flash.
`<pgmspace.h>` there is the definition of PSTR which will place the literal in flash
the patternname, which we normaly just use strcpy, we need to use strcpy_P.
strcpy_P states the string will come from Flashmemory and copy it into SRAM space.  Once it is in SRAM sapce we can maniputate it all we want.
for example:

```
setPatternName((char*)PSTR("My PatternName"));

void setPatternName(const char* text) {
  memset(patternName, MAX_PATTERN_NAME_LEN + 1, 0 );
  strcpy_P(patternName, text);
  int length = strlen(patternName);
}
```

This should have a significant reduction in mem usage.

Answer (score 1):

```
char buf[50];

char* tm1Txt (byte num){
  if (num == 0){strcpy_P(buf, (char*) F("t1 - Задepжka koмaнды xoд"));}
  if (num == 1){strcpy_P(buf, (char*) F("t2 - Bpeмя cepвoфиkcaции "));}
  if (num == 2){strcpy_P(buf, (char*) F("t3 - Bpeмя дoтягивания   "));}
  if (num == 3){strcpy_P(buf, (char*) F("t4 - Bpeмя тopмoжeния    "));}
  if (num == 4){strcpy_P(buf, (char*) F("t5 - Наложениe тормоза   "));}
  if (num == 5){strcpy_P(buf, (char*) F("t6 - Снятия нагр воздуха "));}
  return buf;
}
```